# XCode can't find images in Assets.xcassets after building for Mac Catalyst

Tags: xcode, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have a Mac Catalyst app that can't seem to find my images.  I made a test project with this in the SceneDelegate: `let contentView = Image("image")` and an image named "image" in the assets folder.  This test project builds, so there must be something else I'm doing wrong.

How can I debug the assets folder?  Is there a way to print out all assets or something?
I also opened up the project in DerivedData to try and dig into the build to find the assets, but I also can't seem to find them in there.  Where should the image be in the bundle?

Update: Comparing my main project to my test project (where XCode can find the image), I see that my test project has a file called Assets.car in the Resources folder, but my main project does not.  Is there any reason XCode would not make this file?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had somehow removed the assets folder from "Copy Bundle Resources" in my Build Phases ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to follow:-

1. **Clear derived data
2. Clear build folder
3. Restart your system**

It worked for me hope it works for you as well.